# Function to look for null string and return a space if found

Tags: c#, xslt

I have an XSLT file and inside I have a function that needs to return a space if the value is NULL. However, it is complaining about the line below specifically which is `if (string A == "")`. Would anyone know what is wrong with that?

```
<![CDATA[
    public string TermDate(string A)
    {
        if (string A == "")
            return " ";
        else
            return A;                                                 
    }
]]>

(...)

cs:TermDate(TerminationDate),
```

Comment: you just want `if(A=="")`

Comment: The spacing on this question is epic.

Comment: By "NULL" do you mean null, or empty, or both?

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `string` key word in `if` condition part.

Change

```
if (string A=="")
```

To

```
if (A=="")
```

You can read more about the syntax of if [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5011f09h.aspx).

Comment: This'll do it.  You're creating a variable `A` when you incorporate `string`.  To use the instantiated variable `A`, you simply call it's name.

Comment: sorry about spacing/format guys, i'm an ultra noob at this. I will try to remove the string part. appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(A)) return " ";
else return A;
```

Comment: This is an eloquently solved answer.

Comment: The extra else isn't needed. It will return `A` regardless.

Comment: True, although the answer originally did not have the `else`, I think it was added for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Couple more options (using [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) ) in addition to normal `if(a)...`:

`? :` - [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
return String.IsNullOrEmpty(a) ? " " : a;
```

`??` - [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
return a ?? " ";
```

Comment: Isn't conditional "Ternary"?  Or are they the same?

Comment: @plast1K, "ternary operator" is common name for "conditional operator" `? :`. Historically there is only one "ternary" (as in "with 3 operands") operator in pretty much any language and names used interchangeably.